# Datatables - Change Font Size of Printed Page Title

Tags: css, datatables

I have a problem when attempting to change my printed page title's font.
I've used the **customize** method based on [this documentation](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/print/customisation.html)

and here's my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#tabelservis').DataTable( {
    "columnDefs": [
            { "type": "numeric-comma", targets: [0, 3] }
    ],
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    buttons: [
        {
            extend: 'copyHtml5',
            exportOptions: {
                columns: [ 0, ':visible' ]
            }
        },
        {
            extend: 'excel',
            exportOptions: {
                columns: [ 0,1, 2, 3, 4 ]
            }
        },
        {
            extend: 'print',
            title: 'All of Services',
            exportOptions: {
                columns: [ 0,1, 2, 3, 4 ]
            },
            customize: function ( win ) {
                $(win.document.body)
                    .css( 'font-size', '12px' );

                $(win.document.body).find( 'table' )
                    .css( 'font-size', '12px' );
            }

        }
    ]
} );
} );
```

But still the title font is not changing, here's the screenshot:

[image]

As you can see, the big "All of services" still has big font size.

Any suggestions to solve this? 
Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The title is on `<h1>` html markers.
So You can change all css style for **this** marker.

For example:

```
 customize: function ( doc ) {
     $(doc.document.body).find('h1').css('font-size', '15pt');
     $(doc.document.body).find('h1').css('text-align', 'center'); 
 }
```

Etc. ;)

Comment: Works Great! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Try wrapping your title in a div with style setting the font size:-

```
buttons [
 extend: 'print',
 title: function() {
    return "<div style='font-size: 14px;'>My Title</div>";
  } 

]
```

Comment: This worked, but when I printed the data table through chrome, the header included that div tag information. Not sure how other browsers treat it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this for now

```
$(win.document.body:contains("All of services")).css( 'font-size', '12px' );
```